# MySQL: Why is simple query not using index, performing filesort

Tags: mysql, filesort

I have a table defined like so:

```
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`slug` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`description` text NOT NULL,
`ordinal` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

Let's call it **t1**

In **t1**, I have an index on *ordinal*.

This table only contains a few rows, it's a definitions table so I usually do this, to get the definitions in the order I want them

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE 1 ORDER BY ordinal;
```

If I perform an **EXPLAIN** on that statement, I get the following:

```
id? select_type?    table?  partitions? type?   possible_keys?  key?    key_len?    ref?    rows?   Extra?
1   SIMPLE  t1  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5   Using where; Using filesort
```

It doesn't really matter that the row above is screwed up in alignment. The important part is that it's using filesort and I can't figure out why.

Since it's only 5-10 rows in this table, it can feel like it's not important but the filesort makes my **open_tables** go a bit bananas since MySQL (according to the mighty internet) opens TWO tables for each filesort query it needs to perform.

So, greatful for any help here. Thanks.

Comment: You have 5 rows. I guess it cannot be bothered to use the index on such a small dataset

Comment: The plan notes "Using where", which is a bit of a red flag because your `WHERE` clause is satisfied by every row.  The optimizer likely will focus on join and selection predicates in its analysis of how and whether to use your index.  Possibly your index is ignored because it doesn't help with those.  Removing the `WHERE` altogether might persuade it to consider the index for assisting with the `ORDER BY`.  Alternatively, since there are only a few rows and MySQL has to read them all anyway, it may just be faster to sort them directly.

Comment: John: you may be right. removing the "where 1" doesn't help though. The queer thing is that I really just want it to not create a tmp-table as it does for the filesort since I have an "open table" problem that seem to come - in part - from these queries that has filesorts.

Answer (score 0):

Your table does not have any index on the "ordinal" column that would possibly get utilized.  Also, since your WHERE clause is on a fixed "1" value which is always true, but no column to compare or even LOOK for an index to help, it can't pick anything... So you are going through a filesort... no index applicable to the where and no index applicable to the order by clause.

Comment: The index is there, I just didn't put it in the text above. My main question is really how to avoid a filesort since it comes with bagage. But thanks still for writing an answer.

Comment: @Adergaard, Avoid file sorts by trying to have well planned indexes based on expected query criteria.  Also, learn to utilize compound AND covering indexes.  When dealing with totals and aggregates especially in web, don't be afraid to have higher level total/count columns to prevent constant querying of underlying details.